# Node.js and twilio integration

Tags: node.js, integration, twilio

I am trying to integrate twilio with Node.js+express.

I don't have a site yet. what value should I give for HOSTNAME, along with SID  and AUTH_TOKEN, these values I got from twilio site.

I have written some code, whatever suggestion given below I have placed in to views folder in twiclient.js , I have added a route in app.js to redirect the request if /twi is called , but I am not getting any result. some errors are appearing in the console, would you please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I have placed the correct SID, token and hostname, as specified below.

app.js has the following entry, does anything else need to be done for the twilio calling part to work?

Also, where should I define the GUI for calling a phone in the views folder?

```
var TwilioClient = require('twilio').Client,
      Twiml = require('twilio').Twiml,
      sys = require('sys');
var client = new TwilioClient('MY_ACCOUNT_SID', 'MY_AUTH_TOKEN', 'MY_HOSTNAME');

var phone = client.getPhoneNumber('+2323232323');
phone.setup(function() { phone.makeCall('+15555555555', null, function(call) {});
phone.setup(function() {
    phone.makeCall('+15555555555', null, function(call) {
        call.on('answered', function(callParams, response) {
            response.append(new Twiml.Say('Hey buddy. Let\'s meet for drinks later tonight.'));
            response.send();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hostname is 'api.twilio.com'.  Your SID and AUTH_TOKEN come from your twilio account.  When you log in, go to the dashboard.  You'll find your SID and AUTH_TOKEN listed there.

Here's the code I use to make a request to twilio to place a call.  It should help you get started.

```
var https = require('https');
var qs = require('querystring');

var api = 'your api key';
var auth = 'your auth token';

var postdata = qs.stringify({
    'From' : '+5554321212',
    'To' : '+5552226262',
    'Url' : 'http://yourwebsite.com/call'
});

var options = {
    host: 'api.twilio.com',
    path: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/<your api key>/Calls.xml',
    port: 443,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length' : postdata.length
    },
    auth: api + ':' + auth
};

var request = https.request(options, function(res){
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
    })
})

request.write(postdata);
request.end();
```

Comment: Hi,thanks a lot for your speedy reply. I am new to node.js and twilio, there is no reference to twilio in this code. is twilio is not required here ?

Comment: Hi, I am using Node.js express, in the app.js

Comment: The code snippet above shows you how to POST to the twilio api in order to place a phone call.  You can see in the options the host is api.twilio.com.  This is a self-contained example that you can just copy directly to a empty .js file, save it, and run it.  once you do that, you can include that file in your express project.

Comment: to make it work, you'll need to edit the api, auth, postdata, and options variables and plug in your info from your twilio account.  that help?

Comment: ok, one more thing.  i just looked at the code you included when you edited your post.  I'm not using the twilio npm module; I had no luck getting it to work.  I'm doing it manually by just sending POSTs to the twilio api.  it's easy enough to do.  The twilio npm module just made me want to pull my hair out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed reply, I will immediately check this and accept your answer.